# Issues with inspect.py when used inside Jython

Tags: python, module, jython, inspect

I am using an application developed in Jython. When I try to use the inspect.py in that, it shows error message.

My code goes like this

```
import inspect,os,sys,pprint,imp
def handle_stackframe_without_leak(getframe):
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    try:
        function = inspect.getframeinfo(getframe)
        print inspect.getargvalues(getframe)
    finally:
        del frame
#
def raja(a):
    handle_stackframe_without_leak(inspect.currentframe())
    print a
#
def callraja():
    handle_stackframe_without_leak(inspect.currentframe())
    raja("raja@ad.com")
#
callraja()
raja("raja@ad.com")
#
```

When I run this using python.exe, there are no issues. However, using this inside the app throwing the following error

```
 File "C:\Program Files\jython221ondiffjava\Lib\inspect.py", line 722, in getframeinfo
 File "C:\Program Files\jython221ondiffjava\Lib\inspect.py", line 413, in findsource
 File "C:\Program Files\jython221ondiffjava\Lib\sre.py", line 179, in compile
 File "C:\Program Files\jython221ondiffjava\Lib\sre.py", line 227, in _compile
 File "C:\Program Files\jython221ondiffjava\Lib\sre_compile.py", line 437, in compile
 File "C:\Program Files\jython221ondiffjava\Lib\sre_compile.py", line 421, in _code
 File "C:\Program Files\jython221ondiffjava\Lib\sre_compile.py", line 143, in _compile
ValueError: ('unsupported operand type', 'branch')

    at org.python.core.Py.makeException(Unknown Source)
    at sre_compile$py._compile$1(C:\Program Files\jython221ondiffjava\Lib\sre_compile.py:143)
    at sre_compile$py.call_function(C:\Program Files\jython221ondiffjava\Lib\sre_compile.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
     at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
    at sre_compile$py._code$11(C:\Program Files\jython221ondiffjava\Lib\sre_compile.py:421)
    at sre_compile$py.call_function(C:\Program Files\jython221ondiffjava\Lib\sre_compile.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
    at sre_compile$py.compile$12(C:\Program Files\jython221ondiffjava\Lib\sre_compile.py:437)
    at sre_compile$py.call_function(C:\Program Files\jython221ondiffjava\Lib\sre_compile.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sre$py._compile$13(C:\Program Files\jython221ondiffjava\Lib\sre.py:227)
    at sre$py.call_function(C:\Program Files\jython221ondiffjava\Lib\sre.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
    at sre$py.compile$8(C:\Program Files\jython221ondiffjava\Lib\sre.py:179)
    at sre$py.call_function(C:\Program Files\jython221ondiffjava\Lib\sre.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at inspect$py.findsource$24(C:\Program Files\jython221ondiffjava\Lib\inspect.py:413)
    at inspect$py.call_function(C:\Program Files\jython221ondiffjava\Lib\inspect.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
    at inspect$py.getframeinfo$54(C:\Program Files\jython221ondiffjava\Lib\inspect.py:722)
    at inspect$py.call_function(C:\Program Files\jython221ondiffjava\Lib\inspect.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at custom$py.handle_stackframe_without_leak$4(C:\Program Files\<my app>\jars\custom.py:29)
    at custom$py.call_function(C:\Program Files\<my app>\.\jars\custom.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
    at definitions$py.gotonotificationprofile$122(C:\Program Files\<my app>\.\jars\definitions.py:1738)
    at definitions$py.call_function(C:\Program Files\<my app>\.\jars\definitions.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
    at notificationcases$py.A003$2(C:\Program Files\<my app>\.\jars\notificationcases.py:143)
    at notificationcases$py.call_function(C:\Program Files\<my app>\.\jars\notificationcases.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx171.f$0(003:8)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx171.call_function(003)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(Unknown Source)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Rajasankar

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running your program on the command line with Jython (so outside of the app)?  When I run your program with Jython 2.2.1 or Jython 2.5.0, I get identical output as from Python.

Comment: Working out side the app is working. I am unable to work with the re module inside app. Will check the versions.

Answer (score 0):

This might help http://grinder.sourceforge.net/faq.html#re-problems.

For a quick check, try adding `import re` in findsource method (*C:\Program Files\jython221ondiffjava\Lib\inspect.py*)

```
def findsource(object):
    """Return the entire source file and starting line number for an object.
    (...snip...)"""
    import re
    file = getsourcefile(object) or getfile(object)
```

Can't promise anything, though...